# MySql: Response does not return second query´s result when first query false

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I made a `search` based on `productName`, so whenever the user search for e.g for `product A`, it shows product A, but if it searches for a product I don´t have in my database then it should still display `all the products`.

My `first query` `works fine`, but my `second query` `doesn´t display any products`, when I `console the response on the client` I get an `empty array`. Where is the issue?

Here is my search API:

```
<?php

try {

            // connect to the database
            require 'connect.php';
            // data from the BROWSER
            $sSearch = $_GET['search'];
            // TURN it into UPPERCASE
            strtoupper( $sSearch );
            // create a query: select products where search value equals productName
            $query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName=:productName");
            $query1->bindParam( ':productName' , $sSearch );
            $bResult1 = $query1->execute();
            $ajResult1 = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            $sajResult1 = json_encode( $ajResult1 );
            // create another query: select all products if search does not match any productName
            $query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
            $query2->execute();
            $ajResult2 = $query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            $sajResult2 = json_encode( $ajResult2 );
            $sjResponse = $bResult1 ? $sajResult1 : $sajResult2; 
            echo $sjResponse; 

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "ERROR";

    }

?>
```

Comment: Your `$sjResponse = $bResult1 ? $sajResult1 : $sajResult2;` just checks if `$bResult1 = $query1->execute();` is `true`/`false`. An unsuccessful search will still return `true`, as the query did not fail, it just didn't return any rows. You need to check if the `$ajResult1` array is empty.

Comment: I tried this and still doesn´t work.         `$sjResponse = !empty($sajResult1) ? $sajResult1 : $sajResult2;`